# Magento 2.4.1 + MAMP Pro 6 with SSL - Can't access admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, ssl, mamp

I’ve installed Magento 2.4.1 in MAMP Pro 6 and initially had SSL active in MAMP. The Luma landing page appeared fine but I couldn’t access the admin backend. It returned the 404 page.

I’ve unchecked SSL in MAMP and set *web/secure/use_in_frontend* = 0 and *web/secure/use_in_adminhtml* = 0 from their original value of 1 in the *core_config_data* table, and now I can get access to the admin.

I would like to set SSL in MAMP and still access the admin. I can’t find any answers to this. Can I just ignore SSL while it’s in local dev? Will it cause me problems when it’s in production with an SSL? I don’t understand why it doesn’t work and the recommended settings for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During installation the following commands should be used to avoid the MAMP SSL preventing access to the Magento admin.

--base-url=https://website.local:8890/ --base-url-secure=https://website.local:8890/ --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1

Basically, both urls need to use the https protocol.